# Error using Chatterbot while using a 64-bit system

Tags: python, anaconda, 64-bit, chatterbot

I' am currently trying to develop a Chatbot using pythons open-source 'chatterbot' library and I have run into an error whilst trying to execute a program.

I'm using Python 3.7. on the anaconda terminal i receive the error:

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

after executing the code below though the anaconda terminal, is there something obvious that I' am missing or are there any suggestions for how i could proceed?

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/ben\ChatterBot-master\chatterbot- 
corpus-master\chatterbot_corpus\data\english/'):
        data = open('C:/Users/ben\ChatterBot-master\chatterbot-corpus-
```

master\chatterbot_corpus\data\english/' + files ,'r').readlines()
            bot.train(data)

```
while True:
        message = input ('You:')
        if message.strip() != 'Bye':
                reply = bot.get_response(message)
                print('ChatBot :',reply)
        if message.strip() == 'Bye':
                print('Chatbot : Bye')
                break
```

I expected the terminal to begin the chatbot conversation but i cannot get past this error, i have tried removing and reinstalling python to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is complaining that what you're trying to run is not an executable. I suspect that you're trying to run `something.py` in your terminal. Run `python something.py` instead to have the Python interpreter run your file.

Comment: sorry for not replying in a while, it turned out that i was using anaconda 32bit terminal instead of 64bit, also the packages contained in the environment i was using were not the versions which supported chatterbot in its current state (took a long time to figure which versions were needed) Thank you for your advice though!